# legend figure as global in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, plot

Again with global. I have a function which has `plot` and it allows the user to determine the color by passing string (i.e. `'r'` for red). So far so good. Now, I'm calling this function from the main function multiple times. At the end, I want to use `legend` function to specify each color. Let's say

```
in the main function do:
    draw(..., 'r');
    draw(..., 'b');
    draw(..., 'g');
```

where `...` other parameters. Now how can I use the `legend` to determine `'r', 'b', 'g'`? I know `gcf` gets the current figure, but I couldn't use it with `legend`.

Answer (score 0):

You unfortunately can't use legend, but you can use `set` and `get` for these kinds of properties. It's easiest when you save the handle of each line as you plot it. Example:

```
% Basic plot of a blue and a red line
x = 1:10;
y = x.^2;
figure(1)
hold all
h1 = plot(x,y);
h2 = plot(x,y+10);
hl = legend('one line', 'another line');
hold off

% Get the color (it's a 1x3 RGB vector)
color1 = get(h1, 'Color');

% Change the color of the lines
set(h1, 'Color', 'k')      % now it's black
set(h1, 'Color', [0 0 0])  % alternative syntax
set(h2, 'Color', 'y')      % this is yellow.

% Change legend string
set(hl, 'String', {'Go', 'Steelers'}
```

I hope this helped! If you want to explore what other properties you can `get` and `set` on a given handle, you can call something like `get(h1`)

Comment: thank you but I don't think you got my point. I'm calling `plot` from a function many times. Your example does show nothing about `plot` being called in a function.